# How to send data from frontend react.js to backend API node.js using Axios and return back this data to frontend

Tags: python, reactjs, node.js, axios

I'm try to send data 'statusId, name, startDateTime, endDateTime' from frontend react.js to backend API node.js using Axios and return back this data to my frontend on another page.
I'm stuck with my current code.

Here is my frontend holiday.js where the data must go to API backend.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

import {
    Container, Grid, Paper, Stack, Button, Modal, Box
} from '@mui/material';

import { useAuthContext } from "auth/useAuthContext";
import { useSettingsContext } from 'components/settings';
import 'assets/style.css';
import { CustomAvatar } from 'components/custom-avatar';
import axios from "utils/axios";
import PlaceholderDropdown from 'components/placeholder';
import DateTimeRangePicker from 'components/date-range-picker/DateTimeRangePicker'
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import { MakTimeWidget } from 'components/mak-time/MakTimeWidget';
import Alert from '@mui/material/Alert';


export default function MakHoliday() {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const { user } = useAuthContext();
    const { themeStretch } = useSettingsContext();
    const [statusId, setStatusId] = useState();
    const [name, setName] = useState();
    const [startDateTime, setStartDateTime] = useState(null);
    const [endDateTime, setEndDateTime] = useState(null);
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsButtonDisabled(!(statusId && name && startDateTime && endDateTime));
    }, [statusId, name, startDateTime, endDateTime]);

    const handleStartDateTimeChange = (newValue) => {
        setStartDateTime(newValue);
        // setStartDateTime(newValue ? newValue.toISOString() : null);
    };
    
    const handleEndDateTimeChange = (newValue) => {
        setEndDateTime(newValue);
        // setEndDateTime(newValue ? newValue.toISOString() : null);
    };

    const handleCloseModal = () => {
      setOpenModal(false);
    };

    const handleSendRequest = () => {
        // Construisez l'objet de données à envoyer
        const requestData = {
            statusId,
            name,
            startDateTime: startDateTime ? startDateTime.toString() : null,
            endDateTime: endDateTime ? endDateTime.toString() : null,
        };

        // Utilisez axios ou toute autre bibliothèque pour envoyer une requête POST au backend
        axios.post('/api/v1/holiday/create_holiday', requestData)
            .then(response => {
                // Gérez la réponse réussie ici
                console.log(response.data);
                setOpenModal(true); // Affichez la modal de succès
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Gérez les erreurs ici
                console.error(error);
            });
    };

    return (
        <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: '100%', mt: 3 }}>
            <Grid>
                <Grid sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
                    <Paper sx={{paddingBottom: '30px'}}>
                        <Grid sx={{
                            padding: theme.spacing(2)
                        }}>
                            <Stack sx={{
                                marginX: theme.spacing(3),
                                padding: theme.spacing(0, 0, 2, 1),
                                ...theme.typography.h4,
                                borderBottom: () => `solid 1px ${theme.palette.divider}`
                            }}>Take holiday</Stack>
                        </Grid>
                        <Container maxWidth={themeStretch ? false : 'xl'}>
                                <MakTimeWidget />
                                    <Grid sx={{ display: 'flex', padding: theme.spacing(2), justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }} item xs={12} lg={0} md={0} sm={12}>
                                        <CustomAvatar key={48}
                                            alt={user.first_name}
                                            src={user.profile}
                                            sx={{ width: 80, height: 80 }} />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }} item xs={12} lg={0} md={0} sm={12}>
                                            <Grid sx={{ ...theme.typography.body1 }}>{user.first_name}</Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', paddingBottom: theme.spacing(6), }} item xs={12} lg={0} md={0} sm={12}>
                                            <Grid sx={{ ...theme.typography.caption }}>{user.job_name}</Grid>
                                    </Grid>

                                <PlaceholderDropdown
                                    setStatusId={setStatusId}
                                    setName={setName}
                                />

                            <DateTimeRangePicker 
                                startDateTime={startDateTime ? startDateTime.toString() : null}
                                endDateTime={endDateTime ? endDateTime.toString() : null}
                                handleStartDateTimeChange={handleStartDateTimeChange}
                                handleEndDateTimeChange={handleEndDateTimeChange}
                            />
                            <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            sx={{ 
                                width: '30%', 
                                display: 'flex', 
                                justifyContent: 'center', 
                                alignItems: 'center', 
                                padding: theme.spacing(2), 
                                margin: 'auto', 
                                marginTop: '30px',
                            }}
                            // onClick={handleSendRequest} // Appeler la fonction lors du clic sur le bouton
                            onClick={() => {
                                // setOpenModal(true);
                                handleSendRequest();
                            }}
                            disabled={isButtonDisabled}
                            >
                                send request
                            </Button>

                            {/* Modal pour afficher l'Alert */}
                            <Modal
                              open={openModal}
                              onClose={handleCloseModal}
                              aria-labelledby="modal-title"
                              aria-describedby="modal-description"
                            >
                              <Box sx={{
                                position: 'absolute',
                                top: '50%',
                                left: '50%',
                                transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                                width: 400,
                                p: 4,
                              }}>
                              <Alert severity="success">Your request is sended</Alert>
                              </Box>
                            </Modal>
                        </Container>
                    </Paper>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </FormControl>
    )
}
```

API.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_holiday(request):
    employee_id = request.data.get('employee_id')
    session_id = obtain_session_id()
    statusId = request.data.get('statusId')
    name = request.data.get('name')
    startDateTime = request.data.get('startDateTime')
    endDateTime = request.data.get('endDateTime')
    start_dttime = str(datetime.strptime(startDateTime, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'))
    end_dttime = str(datetime.strptime(endDateTime, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'))
    url = 'https://erp.mak.mn/hr_holidays/create_holiday'
    payload = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "params": {
            "employee_id": int(employee_id),
            "date_from": start_dttime[:-3],
            "date_to": end_dttime[:-3],
            "name": name,
            "holiday_status_id": statusId
        }
    }
    payload_json = json.dumps(payload)
    
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Cookie': 'session_id={};'.format(session_id)}
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload_json, headers=headers)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return Response(data['result']['response'], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(False, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And the frontend were the code should appear allholiday.js

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import {
  Container,
  Grid,
  Paper,
  Stack,
  FormControl,
  Table,
  TableCell,
  TableBody,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TablePagination,
  TableSortLabel,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  Checkbox,
  IconButton,
  Tooltip,
  FormControlLabel,
  Switch,
} from '@mui/material';
import { useAuthContext } from 'auth/useAuthContext';
import { useSettingsContext } from 'components/settings';
import 'assets/style.css';
import { CustomAvatar } from 'components/custom-avatar';
import axios from 'axios';
import { set } from 'lodash';


const AllHoliday = () => {
  const [holidayData, setHolidayData] = useState([]);
  const { user } = useAuthContext();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const { themeStretch } = useSettingsContext();
  const employee_id = user.employee_id;
  const [statusId, setStatusId] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [start_dttime, setStart_dttime] = useState(null);
  const [end_dttime, setEnd_dttime] = useState(null);


    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const body = new FormData();
        body.append('employee_id', employee_id);
        body.append('statusId', statusId);
        body.append('name', name);
        body.append('start_dttime', start_dttime);
        body.append('end_dttime', end_dttime);
    
        const response = await axios.post('api/v1/holiday/create_holiday', body);
        if (response.status === 200) setHolidayData(response.data)
      })();
    }, [employee_id, statusId, name, start_dttime, end_dttime]);
  

    const holidayTable = [
      {
        id: employee_id,
        category: setStatusId,
        details: setName,
        startDate: setStart_dttime,
        endDate: setEnd_dttime,
        numberOfDayTaken: 5,
        status: 'approuved', // 'approuve' ou 'refuse'
      },
    ];

    console.log('employee id =', employee_id)
    console.log('category =', setStatusId)
    console.log('details =', setName)
    console.log('startDate=', setStart_dttime)
    console.log('endDate=', setEnd_dttime)
  // Affichage des données de congé
  return (
    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: '100%', mt: 3 }}>
      <Grid>
        <Grid sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
          <Paper>
            <Grid
              sx={{
                padding: theme.spacing(2),
              }}
            >
              <Stack
                sx={{
                  marginX: theme.spacing(3),
                  padding: theme.spacing(0, 0, 2, 1),
                  ...theme.typography.h4,
                  borderBottom: () => `solid 1px ${theme.palette.divider}`,
                }}
              >
                Бүх амралтын хуваарь
              </Stack>
            </Grid>
            <Container maxWidth={themeStretch ? false : 'xl'}>
              {/* Contenu existant */}
              
              <Grid
                sx={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  padding: theme.spacing(2),
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
                item
                xs={12}
                lg={0}
                md={0}
                sm={12}
              >
                <CustomAvatar
                  key={48}
                  alt={user.first_name}
                  src={user.profile}
                  sx={{ width: 80, height: 80 }}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid
                sx={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
                item
                xs={12}
                lg={0}
                md={0}
                sm={12}
              >
                <Grid sx={{ ...theme.typography.body1 }}>{user.first_name}</Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Grid
                sx={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  paddingBottom: theme.spacing(6),
                }}
                item
                xs={12}
                lg={0}
                md={0}
                sm={12}
              >
                <Grid sx={{ ...theme.typography.caption }}>{user.job_name}</Grid>
              </Grid>

              <TableContainer>
                <Table>
                  <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                      <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Амралт, чөлөөний төрөл</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Тайлбар</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Эхлэх огноо</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Дуусах огноо</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Амралтийн өдөр</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Status</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  </TableHead>
                  <TableBody>
                    {holidayTable.map((request) => (
                      <TableRow key={request.id}>
                        <TableCell>{request.id}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{request.category}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{request.details}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{request.startDate}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{request.endDate}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{request.numberOfDayTaken}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{request.status}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                          {/* {demande.statut === 'approuve' ? (
                            <CheckCircleIcon style={{ color: 'green' }} />
                          ) : (
                            <CancelIcon style={{ color: 'red' }} />
                          )} */}
                        </TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
                  </TableBody>
                </Table>
              </TableContainer>
            </Container>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default AllHoliday;
```

currently just the 'employee_id' appears on my frontend but not the other datas

I don't know if i'm doing good or not. Need some help...

Answer (score 1):

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('api/v1/holiday')
      .then(response => {
        setHolidayData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        // Gérez l'erreur, affichez un message d'erreur à l'utilisateur
      });
}, []); // Exécuté une fois lorsque le composant est monté
```

This useEffect only run 1 time when mounted AllHoliday component because dependency is empty array. So when user created new holiday, this useEffect NOT execute again and don't update new data to holidayData state.
Some simple way solve it:

- Use state manager (as redux, react-query,...) to save list holidays and update it when have any action relative of holiday.
- Create a state MakHoliday component to save list holiday, when API POST return success, request GET to update state. And use props to pass list holiday to AllHoliday component.

Hope it't helful.